# How can I build config.ini for my program?

Tags: c#

Well , as you can see the title . I'm trying to build a config.ini will be located and generated in the exe path automatically .. but . I can't process it . every time I do it , I corrupt the source as a noob .

What am I trying to do?

I wanna this ini to be loaded for the program . and it will modify some options I will set like
( Auto generate path set " I created a form to launch some exes automatically , and every time I run this form , it reset the textboxes to empty fields. " )
( Setting the sql connection automatic like 
sqlconnection = 1 -> when it loads , the sql connection will run automatically with the latest success connection happen in the program
sqlconnection = 0 -> when it loads , it won't load the sql connection . who ran the program should do it manually )

Comment: It's a lot easier to help with your code when you post it.

Comment: please post some code that you have worked.

Comment: In addition to .ini files being ancient there are tons of examples out there on how to use them. So what _specifically_ is the problem that you are having? Please include sample input, output and the code that you have tried that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Not a direct answer, but, the ".Net way" of doing this is to use an `App.config` file, rather than an `.ini` file.

`App.config` lives in the executable's folder, and is an XML file containing the application's configuration.  The .Net framework includes built-in classes and methods for reading/writing the configuration at run-time.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a65txexh.aspx) for more details.

Comment: It sounds like he is also wanting to save user / session preferences for which the app.config would not be a good choice for that.

Comment: @geek - That depends.  .Net 4.5 allows settings to be saved.

Comment: I didn't realize that was being allowed now.  Curious - this seemed to be frowned upon previously - is it being allowed now to try and take a more sand-boxed approach for apps?

Comment: @geek - I'm not sure.  I think it's allowing for the saving of user settings, etc. I'm just going on a quick skim of the MSDN pages I linked to.